# Hive dates: date 'yyyy-MM-dd' vs. 'yyyy-MM-dd' What is the difference?

Tags: sql, date, hive, hiveql, where-clause

What is the difference between referring to a hive date as `date '2020-08-25'` vs. just `'2020-08-25'` without the word date?  Is it two different data types? or are these the exactly the same.  This something I might put into a where statement like below:

```
where somedate<=date'2020-08-25'
```

vs.

```
where somedate<='2020-08-25'
```

Answer (score 0):

`date'2020-08-25'` is a *standard date literal*: it generates a legitimate value of the `date` datatype.

On the other hand, `'2020-08-25'` is a literal *string* (that represents a date, but it could be anything else).

Now what is the best pick for the predicate in your `where` clause? It depends on the datatype of the column you want to compare.

If you have a `date` column, then I would recommend using a literal date. Otherwise, you rely on the ability of the database to understand what you mean, and implicitly convert the string to a date. Each database has its own set of rules to handle such case: in the worst case scenario, it *might* take the wrong decision and decide do string comparison, which would require converting all stored values to string (this depends on the database specification) - which would kill the performance of the query.

If you happen to be storing dates as strings (which usually indicates a bad design), then string comparison is fine.

Answer (score 0):

`date '2020-08-25'` is a literal of type DATE.

`'2020-08-25'` - is a string literal.

String and dates can be implicitly converted, so both your where clauses are functionally identical. Depending on column datatype, implicit conversion may happen. Better use the same type to avoid implicit conversion.

Also DATE can be packed in 4 bytes integer in binary formats. See [HIVE-3910](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/)